# What is the setting for minimum date and time for this random Datetimepicker plugin I've found?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

The setter for jQuery's **datepicker** plugin is

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

But what is the setting for this random **[datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)** plugin I've found?

This sets only the minimum date, not the minimum time.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2012, 11, 20, 8, 30));
```

What is the setter for minimum **date and time** for this plugin?

**EDIT**

I want to set mindate and mintime **after** I initalisated the datetimepicker, not during initialisation.

Comment: A javascript Date object represents both date AND time. If time is not specified, then 00:00:000 is assumed.

Comment: why is it not working as you expect ? do you want to set a mintime for each available day ?

Answer (score 4):

In the page you linked to it shows how to set these options on load:

```
$('#example14').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2010, 11, 20, 8, 30),
    maxDate: new Date(2010, 11, 31, 17, 30)
});
```

The plugin you are using does not allow you to change these settings after initialisation.

Comment: Yo bruv, I don't know but I will up vote you! no worries! have a good one, cheerios :) **Downvoter** please its a good idea to explain rather then just down vote innit! no offense to anyone! have a nice one!

Comment: No, Thats not my answer. I want to set the mindate and mintime after initialisation, not during initialisation.

Comment: Hey @OrangeTux see my answer below I deleted it but I just undeleted so that you can see if that helps? let me know if it doesn't I will delete it again, cheerios!

Comment: @OrangeTux this plugin does not support changing min/max date after initialisation, only the initial date.

Comment: @OrangeTux the only way I can actually see this is using `OnCLose` see the link below I shared. hope that will help, cheerios!